# Using Prepared statement in Dynamic view

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-error-1054

Here is my code

```
Drop procedure if exists test//
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN woeid VARCHAR(15))
  BEGIN
   SET @w1 := woeid;
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW temp 
                   AS
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM test_table gp
                   WHERE gp.name =', @w1);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
Delimiter ;

call test('ABCD');
```

I am getting error as
Error code: 1054. Unknown column 'ABCD' in 'where' clause

Please help.

Comment: @eggyal What is the option?? I need gp.name to be user defined.

Comment: As i am using dynamic views i need to use prepare statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though you're needlessly using views, when some other approach would be more appropriate.

However, the reason it isn't working is that you haven't quoted your string literal, so the resulting SQL contains `WHERE gp.name = ABCD` whereas it at very least needs to be `WHERE gp.name = 'ABCD'`.  You *can* use MySQL's [`QUOTE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function for this purpose, but it's better to parameterise the value:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test//
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN woeid VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
  SET @w1:=woeid, @sql:=CONCAT('
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW temp AS
      SELECT * 
      FROM   test_table
      WHERE  name = ?
  ');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @w1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET @w1:=NULL, @sql:=NULL;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL test('ABCD');
```

Comment: I cannot use this as view's select cannot contain a variable or parameter ERROR 1351

Comment: Awesome. It worked. As i can see it was  problem with QUOTES. Can you please explain what was the issue?

Comment: @user2098662: It's already explained in my answer... did it not make sense?  What don't you understand?